# PHP code is not working

Tags: php

I am working on excercise of a Wrox book and the following code is not displaying anything. Why is the reason for this. Should I change the file name?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<table>
<tr>
<td> <label for=”font”> Select Font: </label> </td>
<td> <select id=”font” name=”font”>
<option value=”Verdana”> Verdana </option>
<option value=”Arial”> Arial </option>
<option value=”Times New Roman”> Times New Roman </option>
</select>
</td>
</tr> <tr>
<td> <label for=”size”> Select Size: </label> </td>
<td> <select id=”size” name=”size”>
<option value=”10px”> 10px </option>
<option value=”12px”> 12px </option>
<option value=”16px”> 16px </option>
<option value=”20px”> 20px </option>
</select>
</td>
</tr> <tr>
<td> <label for=”color”> Select Color: </label> </td>
<td> <select id=”size” name=”size”>
<option value=”black”> black </option>
<option value=”green”> green </option>
<option value=”purple”> purple </option>
<option value=”red”> red </option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</form>

<p <?php
echo ' style=”font-family: ' . $_SESSION['font'] . '; ';
echo 'font-size: ' . $_SESSION['size'] . '; ';
echo 'color: ' . $_SESSION['color'] ';" ';
?>> Text to display </p>
```

thanks,

Nav

Comment: You have some sort of smart quote here: `style=”font-family:` Replace it with a standard double-quote `"`

Comment: Elaborate on "not displaying anything".  If no content is returned at all that usually means there was a server-side error.  Turn on PHP error reporting, check the PHP logs, etc.

Comment: please check my solution. it works for me. you just missed a .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you missed a `.` after `$_SESSION['color']`

Comment: All, this is now closed. I really appreciate all the comments and the answers. it is now working. Thanks again!!